# How to edit channel creator in telethon

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I am trying to edit channel creator using telethon and python but getting error:

> The chat or channel wasn't modified (title, invites, username, admins, etc. are the same) (caused by EditCreatorRequest)

I have tried doing that this way:

```
                async with TelegramClient(name, api_id, api_hash) as client:
                    pwd = await client(functions.account.GetPasswordRequest())
                    my_srp_password = pwd_mod.compute_check(pwd, 'mypassword')
                    result = await cli(functions.channels.EditCreatorRequest(
                        channel='channel_username',
                        user_id=user,
                        password=my_srp_password
                    ))
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Make sure `user` is a different admin who isn't you.